# Firefox JavaScript DOM inspector

Tags: firefox, firebug

I used to use
[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)
for web development, but stopped because newer versions of Firefox have built in Web Developer tools.

However I see that Firebug has a
[JavaScript DOM explorer](http://getfirebug.com/dom). Does Firefox have a similar tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Firefox *Web Console* you can do this. Enter:

```js
window
```

As an added bonus you can export the object using [JSON.prune](http://github.com/Canop/JSON.prune/issues/5), example:

```js
al = {
  replacer: function(br, ch) {
    if (typeof br === 'function')
      return JSON.stringify(br.toString());
    return ch;
  }
};
de = JSON.prune(window, al);
```

and you can copy to the clipboard:

```js
copy(de);
```